# Unintentionally rotated eps

Tags: rotating, eps

I exported an eps graphic with OriginPro. When I include this into my document the graphic is rotated by 90°. Funnily, this happens only to two graphs of four although they are equally formatted (as far as I can tell). The packages `rotating` and `graphicx` did not help me so far. This problem does not occur when I use `XeLaTeX` to compile my document, but I need to use `PDFLaTeX` to automatically number compounds in reaction schemes with `chemstyle`. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ptxauy-cnmr}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ptxauy-cnmra}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$^{13}$C\{H\} NMR spectra}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I use TeXStudio with MiKTeX. Perl is installed.
Here are the eps files:
http://www.filedropper.com/ptxauy-cnmr
http://www.filedropper.com/ptxauy-cnmra

Comment: Please minimize your code! I think we need just two packages here. Please also try the standard class `article` and post your real MWE then. Maybe we will need your eps-file as well. You could start debugging by opening your `eps` in a text-editor and search for `rotate`, `90`, `270` and alike. Please post such lines as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "The packages rotating and graphicx did not help me so far", exactly what have you tried? There are many programmes, that for some strange reason export 90 rotated

Comment: In the eps files I surprisingly only found 'ld/ro/rotate'. However, the peak annotations are each rotated by 90°. I tried the package 'graphicx' and entered '\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,angle=90]{ptxauy-cnmr}' as well as other angles but nothing rotated. I also used 'rotating' and embedded the '\includegraphics' command into '\begin{rotate}{90} %... \end{rotate}' but that threw the figures around the page (they ended up half in the text and half outside the page).

Comment: The files you have uploaded are rotated already. Opened them with sumatraPDF. You will have to search for the issue in your exporting program, edit the `.eps` code somehow (not an expert...), or just rotate the image with `\includegraphics[angle=90]{}`

Comment: Your MWE is not compilable any more. Has `auto-pst-pdf` something to do with the problem?

Comment: This is the minimal example that still worked for me. If I exclude 'auto-pst-pdf' I cannot use 'PDFLaTeX' anymore which I need for my reaction schemes. I am actually not able to open these eps files with sumatraPDF and instead open them with PSV. In PSV the eps files are not already rotated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow worked by using "epstool" as described on http://feng.li/crop-eps/ . For that I downloaded epstool, put the exe-file into the folder where my eps-file was. Then I used Windows Command Prompt, moved to that folder and entered the command as given on the website:

```
epstool --copy --bbox file.eps file_new.eps
```

Please note that the original purpose of this procedure is not to rotate the eps file but to reduce the white space.